# linked list c++ difference between void function and return this

Tags: c++, list, this

I have a question about the differences between 2 styles of coding:

```
void *addfirst (int data){
     head = new Node(int data, head);
     return;
}
```

and the second is:

```
LinkedList *addfirst (int data){
     head = new Node(int data, head);
     return this;
}
```

My prof said that nowadays most people prefer the second choice, but I don't know if there was any advantages, compare with the first one?

Comment: The first version has undefined behavior and is therefore very, very bad. The second does not (if `this` is a `LinkedList*`) and is therefore better.

Comment: assuming ^ that's a typo. There is a theory of thought that says functions should do one thing. Returning something after adding to the list violates that principal. It also makes it harder to give strong exception guarantees. However, it can be useful because it can eliminate the need, for instance, of the caller having to search through the list to find what they just inserted, as an example.

Comment: @Taekahn Many of the standard containers returns something after adding to them. It's usually a reference though, but still.

Comment: You'll find that `LinkedList &addfirst (int data){head = new Node(data, head); return *this; }` is even MORE preferred because with a returned reference you are guaranteed to get an object back (or there's a bug elsewhere) where a pointer could be null and you'll need to add code to make sure it isn't null before you can use it. Also in many cases it's more convenient to use a returned reference than a pointer.

Comment: Side note: `void *` is very rarely used in C++, typically only when interfacing with a C-Style API, because it's easily replaced with a `template` or a base class and sometimes a generalist class like a `std::variant` or `std::any`, which can be easily checked for correctness by the compiler. Any time the compiler can catch a mistake for you, that's one less runtime error you'll need to debug.

Comment: @TedLyngmo A fact of which i'm glad. I'm not an advocate for it, just explaining it. Again, assuming the `void *` was a typo.

Comment: Side note: If that should have been `void addfirst` instead then you don't need to `return` explicitly at all – that's what happens implicitly as soon as the code reaches the end of the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> void *addfirst (int data){
>      head = new Node(int data, head);
>      return;
> }
> ```

The function is declared to return an object of type `void*`. The function returns by returning nothing. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> LinkedList *addfirst (int data){
>      head = new Node(int data, head);
>      return this;
> }
> ```

This function does return an object. The behaviour is well defined.